# How do you use REGEX to extract key => values from JSON with unknown levels of nesting?

Tags: json, regex

I am trying to use regex to extract UPCs from a JSON list, but each UPC is deeply nested. Below is a sample.

```
{"offerId":78352,"tierLevel":null}],"offersEligibleForYourPrice":[]},"pointsEarned":null,"kcEarned":null,"lowestApplicablePrice":16.32},"availability":"In Stock","giftWrappable":false,"specialTypeSku":"N","isBopusEligible":true,"storeInfo":null,"sortOrder":"245000000026","itemMaxAllowedCount":99,"itemMaxAvailableCount":231,"maxQuantityMessage":"You can only purchase 99 of this item. Please select a lower amount and try again","shippingServiceCode":"4","isStoreAvailable":true,"surcharge":null,"sizeRange":"Regular","isBossEligible":true,"UPC":{"image":null,"ID":"889799687018"},"size2":"5T"},{"skuCode":"28960347","images":[{"url":"https://media.kohlsimg.com/is/image/kohls/3747263?wid=350&hei=350&op_sharpen=1","height":"350","width":"350","altText":"Toddler Girl's Disney's Minnie Mouse & Daisy Top & Bottom Set"}],"color":"Multi","size":"2T","price":{"isSuppressed":false,"salePriceStatus":"Sale","salePrice":{"minPrice":24,"maxPrice":null},"regularPriceType":"Regular","regularPrice":{"minPrice":40,"maxPrice":null},"promotion":{"tieredPrice":null,"group":null,"bogo":null},"suppressedPricingText":null,"yourPriceInfo":{"yourPrice":16.32,"yourPriceSavings":7.68,"appliedOffers":[77619,78352],"saveMoreOffers":[],"offersIncludedInYourPrice":[{"offerId":77619,"tierLevel":null},{"offerId":78352,"tierLevel":null}],"offersEligibleForYourPrice":[]},"pointsEarned":null,"kcEarned":null,"lowestApplicablePrice":16.32},"availability":"In Stock","giftWrappable":false,"specialTypeSku":"N","isBopusEligible":true,"storeInfo":null,"sortOrder":"245000000078","itemMaxAllowedCount":99,"itemMaxAvailableCount":483,"maxQuantityMessage":"You can only purchase 99 of this item. Please select a lower amount and try again","shippingServiceCode":"4","isStoreAvailable":true,"surcharge":null,"sizeRange":"Regular","isBossEligible":true,"UPC":{"image":null,"ID":"889799686981"},"size2":"2T"},{"skuCode":"28960348","images":[{"url":"https://media.kohlsimg.com/is/image/kohls/3747263?wid=350&hei=350&op_sharpen=1","height":"350","width":"350","altText":"Toddler Girl's Disney's Minnie Mouse & Daisy Top & Bottom Set"}],"color":"Multi","size":"3T","price":{"isSuppressed":false,"salePriceStatus":"Sale","salePrice":{"minPrice":24,"maxPrice":null},"regularPriceType":"Regular","regularPrice":{"minPrice":40,"maxPrice":null},"promotion":{"tieredPrice":null,"group":null,"bogo":null},"suppressedPricingText":null,"yourPriceInfo":{"yourPrice":16.32,"yourPriceSavings":7.68,"appliedOffers":[77619,78352],"saveMoreOffers":[],"offersIncludedInYourPrice":[{"offerId":77619,"tierLevel":null},
```

Using this regex

```
("UPC":)*("ID":")\w{12}
```

I get this result

```
"ID":"889799686981
```

How can this be improved to grab the ID from the UPC array?

Comment: `jq '.[].UPC.ID' <json_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `("UPC":)*` is not part of your match - the quantifier `*` only matches for a quantity of zero.

I think you want:

```
"UPC":[^}]+"ID":"\w{12}
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/m3I0oaOP66IRqK).

This will only match the ID of a UPC, due to the term `[^}]` which won't allow a `}` character between `UPC` and `ID`, thus tying the to together.

Comment: Very nice. However I only need the UPC, and I am looking for it to grab an unknown amount of them.

Comment: @fwho  Here is the regex in this answer tested on your json and seems to be producing what you want : https://regex101.com/r/fMbPCl/1. You can optionally add a capture group to ID values to only keep them.

Comment: @fwho I have modified it to *only* capture ID's of UPC. The ID is captured in group 1 of the match (scroll down in live demo link to see this).